# Cannot figure out how to create an empty build pipeline from Az Devops CLI

Tags: scripting, azure-devops, command-line-interface, devops, az

I need to setup an empty build pipeline based on the built in Azure pipeline configurations using az devops cli. For example a pipeline for an ASP.Net configuration.  I cannot seem to find any good documentation. I saw one that references having a template in another repo, connect to it to implement which also required manual input.

I am very familiar with using Az DevOps CLI but just stumped on how to get this piece fully automated from the command line.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I'm seeing, it can't be fully automated.  Assuming you've installed the Azure CLI and and Azure DevOps CLI extension, you can run a command like this...

```
az pipelines create --name SampleBuildPipeline --repository reponame --repository-type tfsgit --branch master
```

At this point it asks a few questions, template type, preview yaml file, etc.  As far as I can tell, these questions can not be avoided by passing in arguments.

Comment: Thanks.  Yea that is what I was seeing.  Looks like it is not ready for prime time.